If quaternions are an extension of complex numbers, is there a study of EM wave theory in terms of quaternions?
I find that in standard textbooks and online resources, basic EM wave theory (such as radiation, plane wave solutions, polarization) is discussed by treating fields in terms of complex numbers. Is there a study (textbook/article) which discusses basic EM wave theory in terms of quaternions?
If not, why not? I expect to learn something new or understand something better if I study a generalization/extension of it.
Edit: For example, we categorize the polarization of an EM wave depending on the phase difference between X and Y components of the fields. If $\phi_x = \phi_y = 0$, it is linearly polarized. If their difference is $\pi/2$, it is circularly polarized etc..
What would the equations/categories look like if we treated the waves to have "quaternionic phases" instead of "complex phases"? Below is a screenshot from Balanis's Antenna theory:


There are plenty of that available in the literature.

What do you think the noncommutative nature of quaternions would add substantively to the discussion?

From the very beginning, i.e., in Maxwell's Treatise, it was stressed that EM theory could be recast in terms of quaternions. The main reason such a description did not become popular is that most physicists found it easier to use the vector representation pushed forward by Heaviside, which is present in every textbook on the subject nowadays.

@naturallyInconsistent, I found that the quaternions are used to express the 4 dimensions (x,y,z and t) in theory of relativity. But what I intend to see is the extension in phase equations. For example, a linearly polarized wave is said to have no phase difference between x and y components ($E_x = E_xo * e^{j(\omega t + \phi_x)}$, $E_x = E_xo * e^{j(\omega t + \phi_x)}$). How would this be generalized when, instead of using phases, we use quaternions?

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, please see my comment above

@Buzz, I am just curious to see what happens when we evaluate quaternion differences instead of phase differences in EM wave equations.

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90, please see my edit above

@naturallyInconsistent, please see my edit above

quaternionic phases is something that I've been exploring on my own; this is much rarer to see in the literature. If you find something about it, I'd be interested to see it. At least for basic applications, I think we can have photons that way. However, it is not clear if the resulting theory is equivalent to the complex valued phases version. In any case, it is known that electrons would not be interacting this way, because the quaternion version of electron path integral does not work the same way.

I see, Thanks. Hopefully someone has an explanation/answer for this

There is a generalisation, but it uses the next level up from the quaternions.
There is a type of algebra with a strong geometric interpretation called a Clifford algebra. It can be thought of as a generalisation of vector algebra. It includes vectors that represent lines and lengths, but also includes bivectors representing surfaces and areas, trivectors representing volumes, and so on. It also allows you to combine elements from different grades (scalar, vector, bivector, etc.) using addition and multiplication.
The number of basis elements in each grade follows the pattern of Pascal's triangle. in 2D there is one scalar, two vector, and one bivector dimension. In 3D there is one scalar, three vector, three bivector, and one trivector component. In 4D there is one scalar, four vector, six bivector, four trivector, and one quadvector dimension. And so on.
If you take the even-numbered grades, so that's scalar, bivector, quadvector, etc. these turn out to be closed sub-algebras of the Clifford algebra. In 1D we have the scalars, which is the Real number system. In 2D we have one scalar and one bivector, which turn out to be isomorphic to the Complex numbers. In 3D we have one scalar and three bivector components, which are isomorphic to the Quaternions.
Electromagnetism belongs in the 4D Clifford algebra, the next level up. Specifically, the electromagnetic field is a bivector field with six components, representing each pair of coordinates ($F_{xt}$, $F_{yt}$, $F_{zt}$, $F_{yz}$, $F_{xz}$, $F_{xy}$). We can split it into a 3D vector field and a 3D trivector field by picking an inertial reference frame and mutiplying the bivector by the frame's velocity vector. We get the 'temporal' planes with a time component ($F_{xt}$, $F_{yt}$, $F_{zt}$) as a vector, called the electric field, and the purely spatial planes ($F_{yz}$, $F_{xz}$, $F_{xy}$) as a trivector field, called the magnetic field. This, incidentally, is why the magnetic field is considered a pseudovector (or 'axial' vector) in the usual vector algebra - it behave differently to vectors under reflections.
This split acts a bit like taking the real and imaginary parts, but where each part is a vector instead of a scalar. This is closely related to the Riemann-Silberstein vector. (It has long been noted that treating electric and magnetic fields as real and imaginary components of a complex vector worked nicely with Maxwell's equations, but it didn't transform correctly, so was abandoned. This approach fixes that problem. Since the imaginary unit is a geometric entity, it changes under geometric transformations.)
Maxwell's equations reduce to a single equation $\nabla F=J$. The derivative gives a quantity with vector and trivector components, each of which have to be satisfied separately, and the choice of reference frame splits each of those components in two to yield four equations - the standard Maxwell's equations in vector algebra.
I recommend "Spacetime algebra as a powerful tool for electromagnetism" by Dressel, Bliokh, and Nori for a comprehensive overview. https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.5002
Section 2 gives a brief history of the formalisms used in electromagnetism. Section 3 introduces the algebra from the basics up. Quaternions appear in section 3.7, where it mentions why Maxwell's early attempt to use them didn't work. Sections 5.1 and 7.1 derive Maxwell's equations from the single $\nabla F=0$ in a vaccuum and $\nabla F=J$ with source currents.
The paper is mainly talking about the duality relationship between electric and magnetic fields. It has long been noted that Maxwell's equations look very similar if you swap the electric and magnetic fields with each other. The more general geometric setting allows us to see that they are related by a continuous rotation symmetry. This then turns out to be related to how things worked before electroweak symmetry breaking. But that's only touched on briefly. The main value of the paper in my view is that it gives a good, basic introduction to electromagnetism in this generalised Clifford algebra setting.
But there are lots of other resources for this approach. Search for 'geometric algebra' and 'spacetime algebra' along with 'Clifford algebra' for more.

Would that be valuable?
Basic EM wave theory. You have an accelerating charge.
Radiation comes in a straight line $n$ from the source charge (at an earlier time) to some target charge which is affected (later). The force from the radiation is perpendicular to $n$.
And any periodic function can be approximated by a collection of sine waves, and each of them is in two dimensions perpendicular to $n$.
So we want complex numbers to describe what happens in those two dimensions, but why bother with quaternions? Maybe the things you'd want quaternions for are already cancelled out when you decided on the direction.
On the other hand, we're interested in periodic motion of the source charge. Any periodic motion can be represented by a collection of sine waves. A sine wave in one dimension gives a result like a radio tower, it's linearly polarized.
In two dimensions you can have a source charge that moves in a circle. It can give a result like a circular antenna, circularly polarized perpendicular to the motion, linearly polarized in the plane of the motion, and elliptically polarized in between. Or you could have an elliptical antenna.
In four dimensions you can have a source charge that moves like an elliptical orbit. It speeds up and slows down. Is that worth paying attention to? Maybe. There are charges that move in elliptical orbits, and maybe it's worth paying attention to their radiation.

If one tool is more effective than another, why complicate the task!, for example: Octonic representation of electromagnetic field equations 

https://www.google.com/search?q=1A.+Gsponer+and+J.+P.+Hurni%2C+e-print+arXiv%3Amath-ph%2F0510059.&rlz=1C1AVNE_enBE721BE758&oq=1A.+Gsponer+and+J.+P.+Hurni%2C+e-print+arXiv%3Amath-ph%2F0510059.&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOdIBCTIzMjFqMGoxNagCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
